# estimate the position of the item to be searched based on the max value (last item), min value (first item) and the search value using binary search

Tags: python, data-structures, binary-search

My code:

```
    def binary_search(seq,item):
    """It uses non recursive method to search the item in the given seq. 
       It returns the position of item if found, None otherwise"""

    left_index=0
    right_index=len(seq)-1
    while left_index <= right_index:            #stop searching when left_index >   right_indext
    mid_index=(right_index + left_index)//2 #find the mid point
    if seq[mid_index]==item:
    return mid_index
    elif seq[mid_index]>item:
    right_index = mid_index -1          #if mid point ele > search ele, move right pointer
    else:  
    left_index = mid_index + 1        #if mid point ele < search ele, move left pointer
    return None
    a=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
    print(binary_search(a,6))
```

```
Output: "5"
```

How can I improve my code above?

I would like to estimate the position of the `item` to be searched based on the `max value` (last item),`min value` (first item) and the `search value`. My above code is using the middle of the `list` to search which will take a longer time to reach.

Can anyone tell me where I can change my codes and further improve it?

Comment: Please give us more information. What does your code do? Does it raise an error? Is the output different from what you expect? How so?

Comment: Welcome to SO. It seems you have a specific use case and designed a minimal reproducible example for us. Don't get me wrong, that is a good thing! However, to give an educated answer to your question, there's several things we still need to know: will the list always be (nearly) sorted? Is anything known about the increment between the list elements? If the answer to any of these questions is "no", then I cannot think of a way to estimate the position of an element within the list

Comment: What do you mean by "estimate"? The purpose of a search algorithm like binary search is to find the exact position. If you mean you want to interpolate based on where the target should be if the numbers are uniformly distributed, then you are writing an interpolation search, not a binary search. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation_search

Comment: Yes, it sounds like what you're looking for is the Interpolation search.